# How to search all of a groups repositories for a file by name in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I am looking for a project that contains a file, i.e. prometheus.yml. This will help me find which project is the prometheus server, out of the 50-100 projects in my group. I assumed gitlab would provide the ability to do a broad search for a file by name, but I am not seeing such feature. But perhaps my query syntax needs to be special. I remember github having this ability in my last company. But in gitlab, I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible if your gitlab instance is premium tier or higher. In that tier you can use the [advanced search](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/advanced_search.html) feature and search for a file with advanced search filters, e.g.

```
filename:prometheus.yml
```

Another option would be to use [gitlab-search](https://github.com/phillipj/gitlab-search) if you are using the free tier.